# Когда правильно употреблять слово "ваш", а когда "вас"?

Tags: семантика

Чем слово "ваш" отличается от "вас"? Для иностранца по смыслу эти слова очень близки.

Answer (score 1):

Эти слова отвечают на разные вопросы и являются разными частями речи.

Чей? - ваш (мой, твой, его, её, их), слово (притяжательное местоимение) указывает на признак по принадлежности кому-либо.

Вижу кого? - вас (меня, тебя, его, её, их), слово (местоимение) в винительном падеже; нет кого? -  вас (меня, тебя, его, её, их) - родительный падеж; думаю о ком? - о вас (обо мне, о тебе, о нём, о ней, о них).

***Когда я слушаю вас*** (кого?)***, я вспоминаю ваше*** (чьё?) ***триумфальное выступление в "Эрмитаже"...***

---

> > При взгляде на весенние цветы,
> >
> > желтые и белые,
> >
> > милые своею простотой,
> >
> > я вспоминаю ***Ваши*** щеки,
> >
> > горящие румянцем зари,
> >
> > смутной и страстно тревожащей.
>
> Глядя на быстрые речки,
>
> > пенящиеся, бурливые,
> >
> > уносящие бревна и ветки,
> >
> > дробящие отраженную голубизну небес,
> >
> > думаю я о карих,
> >
> > стоячих,
> >
> > волнующих своею неподвижностью
> >
> > глазах.
>
> И, следя по вечернему небу
>
> > за медленным трепетом
> >
> > знамен фабричного дыма,
> >
> > я вижу ***Ваши*** волосы,
> >
> > не развивающиеся,
> >
> > короткие,
> >
> > и даже еще более короткие,
> >
> > когда я видел ***Вас*** последний раз.
>
> Целую ночь, целый день
>
> > я слышу шум машин,
> >
> > как биенье неустанного сердца,
> >
> > и все утра, все вечера
> >
> > меня мучит мысль ***о Вашем*** сердце,
> >
> > которое - увы! - бьется не для меня,
> >
> > не для меня!

[*Май 1907*](https://45parallel.net/anthology/mikhail_kuzmin/pri_vzglyade_na_vesennie_tsvety.html)

Здесь: ваши - чьи? о вашем - о чьём? вас - кого?

Answer (score 1):

«У меня ― мой характер, у Вас ― Ваш характер, у нее ― ее характер». [Александр Клейн. Алхимическая формула Творца // «Пятое измерение», 2003]

«Но скажите, если бы Уил мог содержать себя и вас, ваш отец и вы не стали бы противиться браку с бедным калекой?» [Е. Ахматова (перевод из Э. Булвер-Литтона). Кенелм Чиллингли, его приключения и взгляды на жизнь (1873)]

«Теперь уже поздно противиться судьбе моей; воспоминания об вас, ваш милый, несравненный образ отныне будет мучением и отрадою жизни моей…» [А. С. Пушкин. Повести покойного Ивана Петровича Белкина/Метель (1830)]

Местоимение Вас (в единственном числе, - «тебя»), - производное от «Вы (ты)».
Смысл притяжательного местоимения «Ваш» («твой», - в ед. числе) может быть передан сочетаниями слов: «принадлежащий Вам (тебе)»  или «сделанный Вами (тобой)».

Вас не должно смущать (иначе, - Вы не должны переживать по тому поводу), что Ваш компьютер не воспроизводит знаков кириллицы. Попробуйте составить и написать фразу, в которой смыслы слов «Вас» и «Ваш» становятся для Вас неразличимыми.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день! 
"Ваш" - это притяжательное местоимение, выражающее принадлежность чего-либо (кого-либо) кому-либо, например, "ваш сын". "Сын вас" - это уже некорректно для русского языка, хоть по смыслу и идентично, так не говорят. А "вас" - это, прежде всего, местоимение "вы" в одном из падежей (родительном, винительном, предложном).